# Table value are not changing

Tags: php, mysql, json

***There is my code of EDIT.php DB_Functions,and g.php..I'm not geting where is the fault is anyone here who can help me to find out mistake on my code***

*Every things happen as easy but change in table is not reflecting..my SQL query is working properly on XAMP server..
  It may be silly mistake but not able to find it..*
     **edit.php**

```
<?php 
//error_reporting(0);
include("class_db.php"); 
include_once('DB_Functions.php');

            if (isset ($_GET['edit_id']))
         {
            $id=$_GET['edit_id'];
         {
            if(isset($_POST['nam']))
         {
            $id =($_POST['edit_id']);           
            $name=($_POST['name']);
            $lastname=($_POST['lastname']);
            $email=($_POST['email']);
            $duser=($_POST['duser']);
            $pass=($_POST['pass']);             
            $mob=($_POST['mob']);
            $website=($_POST['website']);


$result =  file_get_contents('http://localhost/rajju/demo/webservises/webservises/webservices/g.php?action=update_details&id='.$id.'&name='.$name.'&lastname='.$lastname.'&email='.$email.'&duser='.$duser.'&pass='.$pass.'&mob='.$mob.'&website='.$website);

$result = json_decode($result, true);

             if($result == 'success'){

             header("location:http://localhost/rajju/demo/webservises/webservises/webservices/list.php");
            }
            else{
                print_r($result);
            } 

         }

         }
         }
$select =mysql_query("select * from users where id=$id");
$var = mysql_fetch_object($select);


?>
```

**DB_Functions.php**

```
public function  updateUser($id,$name,$lastname,$email,$duser,$pass,$mob,$website) 

{ 
$app_list =mysql_query("UPDATE users SET name='".$name."',lastname='".$lastname."',email='".$email."',duser='".$duser."',pass='".$pass."',mob='".$mob."',website='".$website."' WHERE id='".$id."'");

    if ($app_list) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    } 
}
```

**g.php**

```
else if($tag == 'update_details')
{
 $db = new DB_Functions();      
 //$id = ($_GET['id']);
 $name=($_GET['name']);     
 $lastname=($_GET['lastname']); 
 $email=($_GET['email']);   
 $duser=($_GET['duser']);   
 $pass=($_GET['pass']);
 $mob=($_GET['mob']);   
 $website=($_GET['website']);   

    //exit (json_encode($name));

    if ($db ->updateUser($name,$lastname,$email,$duser,$pass,$mob,$website)) 
    {
            exit (json_encode('success'));

    }else
    {
            exit (json_encode('errorzz'));

    } 

}
```

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to injection, xss etc. Firstly look into using `PDO` or `mysqli`. Regarding your issue. If you echo the supposed sql command and try running that through `phpmyadmin`, does it return any error messages?

Comment: no messages returns ..how to solve this problem

Comment: did it update the database then?

Comment: yes..when i did it through phpmyadmin..it get update..but when i do it through php page..it donot sho any updated result..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work. Note this still wont totally protect you against `xss` and other attacks. However its a lot better than using `mysql_query`!! Additionally, you should sanatise and check your incoming `$_GET` params and Salt+Hash your passwords.

```
<?php 
    $conn   = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
    $sql    = "UPDATE users SET name=:name, lastname=:lastname, email=:email, duser=:duser, pass=:pass, mob=:mob, website=:website, WHERE id=:id";;
    $st     = $conn->prepare( $sql );
    $st->bindValue(":name", $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $st->bindValue(":lastname", $lastname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $st->bindValue(":email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $st->bindValue(":duser", $duser, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $st->bindValue(":pass", $pass, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $st->bindValue(":mob", $mob, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $st->bindValue(":website", $website, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $st->bindValue(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $st->execute();
?>
```